# React javascript check if string contains specific word and add something like link react router / styles to specific word

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

is there any solution how to check strings(ex:Google) and add Link react router into specific word(ex:Google)?

example like this photo

before

[image: before]

after

[image: after]

this is my very simple code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "Google is my Friend, Google is Search Engine, Thanks to google"
    website: "Google Friend"
  };

  render() {
    let text = null;
    if (this.state.text.includes(this.state.website)) {
      return (text = (
        <div>
          <Link to={"/example"}>Google </Link> then state text
        </div>
      ));
    }
    return <div>{text}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

it would be more helpful if you can show me how to add style inside specific word(ex: Google) like changing color, or adding bold/italic or anything

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{this.state.text.split(" ").map(text => {
   return text === "Google" ? <Link to="/google">Google</Link> : text;
})}
```

Comment: You can add a space after every value.

Comment: thanks, another question, let say i have another state called this.state.website: "Google Friend" and put it inside includes(this.state.website), and it doesnt work because i think .includes are sensitive or whatever is called. do you have any solution how to solve that?

Comment: Before validating through `includes` change case of both to lower case using `toLowerCase()`

Comment: it still not working because i think includes affect one word only. also check my edited post